# Как спарсить дату с таймзоной в django?

Tags: python, django, timezone

Есть вот такая дата с таймзоной +00:00, которую нужно запихнуть в DateTimeField

```
'2016-04-21T18:00:46.582Z'
```

django.utils.dateparse.parse_date() возвращает None, strftime возвращает naive datetime, от чего, судя по всему, объект не сохраняется. Как сделать это правильно?

Answer (score 1):

`parse_date` парсит только дату, а для даты-времени используется `parse_datetime`, который вполне себе aware:

```
>>> from django.utils import dateparse, timezone
>>> d = dateparse.parse_datetime('2016-04-21T18:00:46.582Z')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 21, 18, 0, 46, 582000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> d.tzinfo
<UTC>
>>> timezone.is_naive(d)
False
```